# how to add image made in canvas to expandablelistview (group)

Tags: android

i have made a bar graph using canvas class.I want to display the bar graph as the main element of my group( instead of the group data).Such that on clicking the 'bar graph' the children will be displayed. The child data will contain normal text.

Comment: can't you make bitmap from canvas and then use it your way?

Comment: You can add the drawable to the group using the

setGroupIndicator(Drawable)

method of ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class extending View and in its onDraw method draw your bar on Canvas.
In your custom ExpandableListAdapter you should create instances of your custom View.